# How to change shell from script

Tags: bash, scripting, ksh

I want to change shell from ksh to bash and source the `.kshrc` file. 
I want to execute following lines of command sequentially:

```
bash
. ~/.kshrc
clear
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does it have to be a script? Or do you just want to be able to do all that in one command?

Comment: You want that to be executed everytime you open a new terminal or what?

Comment: Do you mean `chsh`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to work through this interactively first, then in a script.  What you have typed in your question would work interactively, if the first line of your kshrc file is NOT `#~/usr/bin/env ksh` or `#!/usr/bin/ksh` or something similar.  So, I'll assume we want skip the first line of kshrc file and (try to) execute the rest of the file.

As an example, suppose the following is the entire contents of $HOME/.kshrc

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
# this is my kshrc file
KSH_RED="\033[1;31m"
KSH_RESET="\033[00m"
KSH_SENTINEL="${KSH_RED}Hello from KSHRC${KSH_RESET}"
```

We can use the sentinel variable to indicate whether or not the file executed.  You might want to add the above commands to your $HOME/.kshrc file in order to use the code that follows.  Or, you might want to put the above commands in a kshrc2 file, and make suitable modifications to the code that follows.

Assuming to have above commands in your $HOME/.kshrc, start a new Korn shell.  Let's try the following commands interactively in a Korn shell:

```
echo $KSH_SENTINEL
KSH_SENTINEL=""
echo $KSH_SENTINEL

tail -n +2 $HOME/.kshrc > /tmp/kshrc.bash
bash
. /tmp/kshrc.bash
rm /tmp/kshrc.bash
echo $KSH_SENTINEL
```

The above leaves us in an interactive Bourne-again shell with the environment variable KSH_SENTINEL from the kshrc set.  It also has the environment variables from any bashrc file set, which we might not want.  We could have entered the Bourne-again shell using our /tmp/kshrc.bash file instead of our bashrc by executing the following at our Korn shell prompt:

```
KSH_SENTINEL=""
tail -n +2 $HOME/.kshrc > /tmp/kshrc.bash
echo "rm -f /tmp/kshrc" >> /tmp/kshrc.bash
bash -rcfile /tmp/kshrc.bash
echo $KSH_SENTINEL
```

So far we have been able to enter an interactive Bourne-again shell and set the environment according to a very simple kshrc file.  We did this with a temporary file, /tmp/kshrc.bash, which was removed the first time is is sourced.

Of course bash might choke on some of the ksh syntax or commands in a more complicated kshrc file.  But, if we are only setting environment variables and creating aliases in our kshrc file, then we should be able to use what we've done so far.  If we need to execute only the sections of the kshrc that are compatible with bash, we might use comments to delineate those sections.  Then, we could use awk or something to copy those sections to the /tmp/kshrc.bash file.

Now let's write a Korn shell script (like the original question asked for) that uses these concepts.  The script starts in a Korn shell, extracts commands from the kshrc file, appends the bash commands, executes kshrc+bash commands, and returns to the Korn shell.  Let's call this ksh script "bash_my_korn.ksh".  Here is one version

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

#
# Say hello with the print command (ksh only)
print "Hello from $0"

#
# Set a variable for the temporary file
TMP_FILE="/tmp/kshrc.bash"

#
# Unset the sentinel
KSH_SENTINEL=""
print "Korn sentinel is $KSH_SENTINEL"

#
# Assemble the bash script in 2 sections
# Section 1:

print "#!/usr/bin/env bash" > $TMP_FILE
tail -n +2 $HOME/.kshrc >> $TMP_FILE

#
# Section 2 is the bash commands that we want to
# execute after the kshrc commands are executed
cat >> $TMP_FILE <<-EOS

echo "Hello from the Bourne-again shell"

if [[ -z "\$KSH_SENTINEL" ]] ; then
    echo "Bash can NOT see the sentinel variable"
else
    echo -e "Bash can see sentinel \$KSH_SENTINEL"
fi
print "Bash shell does not know the print command"

echo "Goodbye from Bourne-again shell"
EOS

#
# The bash command file now exits.  There are several ways to execute it.
print
print "Method 1, without the bashrc file"
bash --norc $TMP_FILE

print
print "Method 2, requires the script be executable"
chmod u+x $TMP_FILE
$TMP_FILE           # the bash command is on the first line of the script

#
# Now finish the Korn shell script
print
print "Goodbye from $0"

#
# Clean up ?
rm -f $TMP_FILE
```

Hopefully the comments in the above script will explain it.  The idea is to assemble a single bash script containing both the kshrc commands and the bash commands then simple execute that script.  The example ksh script contains a bunch of print commands, so you can see what sections are being executed.  The script could delete itself, but it's probably better for the Korn shell that created the script to also delete it.

Let me make a few comments.  First, notice we can start bash with `--norc` option to avoid executing the usual bashrc file.  Second, we can us `cat` to append commands to the bash script, but if the bash commands contain environment variables, we need to put a backslash in front of the dollar sign to prevent the Korn shell from expanding the variable, as we did above.  Third, this demo should be considered as proof of concept to get you started on your own solution.